# how do I get pixel values or windows x/y positions to style accordingly to those coordinates?

Tags: css

How can I get an element to change it's style according to my mouse position in that element during a hover?

*For example:*

If I hover my mouse on the top-left part (maybe 20% from top and 20% left) of the div, I would like to apply style A on this div but if I hover on the bottom-right part (maybe 20% from bottom and 20% from right) of the div I would like to apply style B instead.

*The main question is:*

**How do I get those**

- **20% from top and 20% left**
- **20% from bottom and 20% from right**

**coordinates to use with div:hover selector?**

Comment: You can't do it with just CSS, you should use Javascript for. read about `mouseover` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solutions below, let's say we have an element with 400px of width and 300px of height.

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

```
.element {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #333;
}
```

**Solution 1: with CSS only**

Solving the example you gave, we have to wrap the div in a container element with two spans before the div as auxiliary elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="left-top-20"></span>
  <span class="right-bottom-20"></span>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Then, we position the `<span>` elements in the corners. For this we set `position: relative` to the container and `position: absolute` to the spans and top, right, bottom and left properties.
Finally, hovering the spans will affect the `.element` style using general sibling selector `~`;

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.container span {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-top-20 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.right-bottom-20 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.left-top-20:hover ~ .element {
  background-color: red;
}
.right-bottom-20:hover ~ .element {
  background-color: green;
}
.element {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #333;
}
```

A drawback of this is that the spans will be in front of the div element, so they will prevent any interaction with what is underneath, such as selecting text or clicking any button.

**Solution 2: with JavaScript**

For this solution, you don't need container or auxiliary elements.
First, you add a listener for hovering the element, the `mousemove` event listener. Every time the mouse moves inside the element, its height and width will be stored, as well as the position of the mouse inside it.
Lastly, the conditional and calculation will be made to check if the position is where you want it to be, adding classes to style the div, or removing them.

```
.element {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #333;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```
document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  var elementWidth = this.offsetWidth;
  var elementHeight = this.offsetHeight;
  var positionHorizontal = e.offsetX;
  var positionVertical = e.offsetY;

  if (positionHorizontal <= elementWidth * 0.2 && positionVertical <= elementHeight * 0.2) {
    this.classList.add('red');
  } else if (positionHorizontal >= (elementWidth - (elementWidth * 0.2)) && positionVertical >= (elementHeight - (elementHeight * 0.2))) {
    this.classList.add('green');
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('red', 'green');
  }

});
```

Another event listener is also needed to check if the mouse has left the element. This is for situations where the mouse was in one of the corners before leaving, so the style will be removed. Otherwise, the style would remain applied even with the mouse out.

```
document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  this.classList.remove('red', 'green');
});
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that it has a worse performance than the first solution.